# Lyx CV modern \cventry not aligned

Tags: latex, lyx

I'm new using lyx and learning LaTex. I have to make myself a CV. You may found below the latex code taken lyx LaTex overview, the lyx window, and the pdf overview. Normally the dates are supposed to be aligned under the section title but instead it generates a dot and them my text not aligned as supposed. Looking at the lyx latex overview window we can see that it automaticaly follow my \cventry by {}{}{}{}{} and them my text.

You can see the overview clicking on the link below
[Cv overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qv2D.png)

Any idea ? :) thanks !

```
% Visionner le code LaTeX

%% LyX 2.3.3 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{moderncv}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1cm,bmargin=1cm,lmargin=1cm,rmargin=1cm}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{2}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}
\usepackage{float}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{xmpmulti}

\moderncvtheme[grey]{classic}
\firstname{Charp******}
\familyname{Paul}
\title{CV Académique}
\address{92 rue *******}{Saint Cloud 92210}
\mobile{+33 6 ** ** ** **}
\email{paul.charp_____@imt-atlantique.net}
\photo[120pt]{photoCV.jpg}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section{Formation}

\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{2029--2020}{IMT Atlantique }{Fusion des ex-Mines de Nantes et
de Télécom Bretagne}{}{}

\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{2018--2019}{CPGE MP option info à Hoche }{}{}

\section{Recherche et Bureau d'étude}

\cventry{}{}{}{}{}{test}{}{}

\section{Expériences professionnelles}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works! just changed the arrangements of brackets, the output i get is similar to yours.

```
...
...

\section{Formation}

\cventry
{}{2019 -- 2020}
{}{}{IMT Atlantique}{Fusion des ex-Mines de Nantes et de Télécom Bretagne}

\cventry
{}{2018 -- 2019}
{}{}{CPGE MP}{option info à Hoche}

\section{Recherc}

\cventry
{}{2018 -- 2019}
{}{}{CPGE MP}{option info à Hoche}
```

definition of a cv-item: (cv-entry is a part of cv-item)

```
\cvitem[#1]{#2}{%
    {\bfseries#3}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#4}{}}{}{, {\slshape#4}}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#5}{}}{}{, #5}%
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#6}{}}{}{, #6}%
    .\strut%
    \ifx&#7&%
    \else{\newline{}\begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}\small#7\end{minipage}}
    \fi}}
```

you can also use bulleted list(s) to look better; i mean it looks good to me

```
\section{Expériences professionnelles}
\cventry
{}{Exp 1}{}{}{}{}
\cvlistitem{lorem ipsum odor sit amet}
\cvlistitem{lorem ipsum odor sit amet}

\cventry
{}{Exp 2}{}{}{}{}
\cvlistitem{lorem ipsum odor sit amet}
\cvlistitem{lorem ipsum odor sit amet}
```

& here's the result...

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answers :). The empty brackets are automaticaly generated by ly. How do I change them ?

Comment: open it with any text-editor & remove unnecessary braces